# How to display a simple messsage using WPF and MVVM

Tags: mvvm

I've look online at several different resources to find a simple example of commands inside C# using the MVVM and WPF. All I
want to know is how to display a message after a button has been clicked. I couldn't find anything this simple online so I'm
asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends really on the nature of the message, from where it comes from and at when should it be displayed. While it's for sure an operation that is more view-related, the source may come from business logic that may merit being in the viewmodel for testing.

Generally speaking, I would choose one of two approaches:

- Use normal dependency injection when building the view-model, and inject a service (via its interface) that will be in charge of displaying all messages. The real implementation may be simple as a call to `MessageBox.Show` or do more complicated things at the view level.
- Give the view-model an event for it to raise, containing all the message data in its `EventArgs` parameter. The view will subscribe to that event and display the notification as it pleases.

In both cases, the view-model is unaware of view specific logic, while still able to encapsulate business logic for message generation, and being fully unit-testable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, "simple" things such as displaying a message in a `Window` tend to violate MVVM from a purist standpoint, or require a fair amount of code to build a system where this works cleanly.

That being said, *in most cases*, showing a message is often a pure view concern.  As such, this is something where I'll often just do it in code behind in the View.  At first, this may seem like it violates MVVM, but as it's a "pure-View" related operation, it's not really a problem in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways
1. You can just put a message Box in the View-Model on Execute of the ICommand, when you click on the Button, Message box will pop up or
2. You can have Message on the hidden on the Xaml, and make it visible when you click on Button